# Angular reactive form child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like create reusable input group component with DE/EN data.

I'm looking for, once all the mandatory fields are filled for EN and DE then submit button should get enabled. And also should get all the data in JSON format.

Here the sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avjyct?file=app/app.component.ts

I have been trying but stuck. Expert advise please?

Comment: Please clarify which problem are you having...

Comment: To clarify, all four fields need to be filled?

Comment: @Avin: Yes, it should be filled all four.

Comment: @agascon: I'm unable to enable the submit button since mandate fields are not binding the data properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you wanted to pass string value to your child component but passed `undefined` instead:

```
[en]="label1_en"
      ^^^^^^^^^
there is no such property in your component.
```

You can pass string like:

```
[en]="'label1_en'"
```

or

```
en="label1_en"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqyr1q?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped