# Angular - Interact with reactive forms of child components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a registration component that has a ng-switch of components

```html
<ion-component>
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="registrationStage">
    <step1 *ngSwitchCase="1"></step1>
    <step2 *ngSwitchCase="2"></step2>
    <step3 *ngSwitchCase="3"></step3>
  <ng-container>
</ion-component>

<ion-footer>
  <button (click)="goForward()">
  </button>
</ion-footer>
```

#### registraion component

```js
  private goForward(): void {
    if (this.section !== 5) {
      switch (this.section) {
        case 1:
          this.step1.nextStep(); // <---cannot read property invalid of undefined
          this.regService.goForward();
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

#### step1 component

```js
export class Step1 {
  private regForm: FormGroup;
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder;
  private stepTwo = false;

  public constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formBuilder = formBuilder;
  }
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('loaded'); //<-- I see this in the console

    this.regForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
        confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
      },
      {
        validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword'),
      },
    );
  }
  public verifyAndNextStep(): void {
    this.stepTwo = true;

    if (this.regForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const emailPassword: EmailPassword = {
      email: this.regForm.value.email,
      password: this.regForm.value.password,
    };
    this.regService.setEmailAndPassword(emailPassword);
    this.regService.goForward();
  }
```

the problem is that I get an error saying: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined` pointing to the function call above. Furthermore it appears that the FormGroup is not getting initialized?

I am not sure exactly what the problem is, I have looked at other posts about this:

[one](https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664)

[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541130/angular-reactive-form-child-component)

[STACK BLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xm9xrh?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: Where is step1 initialized? Can you provide a Stackblitz with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting your component directly instead of fetching it from view like this

```
  public constructor(navCtrl: NavController, step1: StepOne) {
}
```

Such component will be a 'plain object' without angular's component lifecycle involved. Therefore no `ngOnInit`is called in `Step1` so no form is created thus `form` is undefined

What you should do, instead of constructor injection, use `@ViewChild`  to get actual component from the page.

This fixes your issue (at step 1 at least, didnt check anything else)

```
 @ViewChild(StepOne)
  private step1: StepOne;
  private navCtrl: NavController;
  public constructor(navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-quz7y3?file=pages/home/home.ts

Comment: awesome! that solved it, the only thing that I had to edit from your example is `@ViewChild(StepOne, { static: false }) private step1: StepOne;` because with angular 8 you need to pass [metadata properties](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

Comment: because stackblitz is on angular 7

Answer (score -1):

replace (this.regForm.invalid) with (this.regForm.status === 'INVALID').

formbuilder  do not have Invalid/valid property [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6rQV.png)

Comment: hi, according to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#invalid) there is a `invalid` method that returns a boolean. it's better sometimes to read the documentation than go off of the Dev Tools